# Combine duplicate rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing 401k and Roth contributions (type of 4 is a 401k, type of R is a roth) and employer matching amounts for each contribution type:

| id | name | contrib | match | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 100 | 50 | 4 |
| 2 | Sue | 500 | 30 | 4 |
| 3 | Tom | 150 | 80 | 4 |
| 4 | Fred | 200 | 10 | 4 |
| 5 | Sue | 150 | 5 | R |
| 6 | Jane | 125 | 40 | 4 |

I need a query that will pull all of the names and their contribution amounts and then sum the matching amounts on one line, if they have a roth and a 401k. output will look like this:

| name | contrib (401k) | match (combined) | contrib (roth) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 100 | 50 |  |
| Sue | 500 | 35 | 150 |
| Tom | 150 | 80 |  |
| Fred | 200 | 10 |  |
| Jane | 125 | 40 |  |

Not everyone will have a roth contribution but, if they do, then it needs to be combined with their 401k contribution on one line.  In the example above, Sue will have one line with her 401k contribution, the combined matching amount and her roth contribution all on one line.

I've tried group_by, sum(), max(), min(), joins, unions and just about everything else I can think of but it always ends the same way with Sue having 2 lines.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that everyone will have 401k contribution, and some of them will have roth contribution. Please try the query below *(Note. Not tested)*

```sql
select TradContrib.name,
    greatest(max(TradContrib.contrib), isnull(max(RothContrib.contrib), 0)) as contrib,
    sum(TradContrib.contrib) as trad_contrib,
    sum(RothContrib.contrib) as roth_contrib
from dbo.EmployeeContribution as TradContrib
left outer join dbo.EmployeeContribution as RothContrib on RothContrib.name = TradContrib.name and RothContrib.type = 'R'
where TradContrib.type = 4

group by TradContrib.name
```

—————-——————————

For older versions of sql server:

```sql
select TradContrib.name,
    iff(max(TradContrib.contrib) > isnull(max(RothContrib.contrib), 0), max(TradContrib.contrib), isnull(max(RothContrib.contrib), 0)) as contrib,
    sum(TradContrib.contrib) as trad_contrib,
    sum(RothContrib.contrib) as roth_contrib
from dbo.EmployeeContribution as TradContrib
left outer join dbo.EmployeeContribution as RothContrib on RothContrib.name = TradContrib.name and RothContrib.type = 'R'
where TradContrib.type = 4

group by TradContrib.name
```

Comment: This might work if RothContrib.contrib gets an IsNull check. Plus the function Greatest() really depends on the version as it is fairly new in SQL OnPrem.

Comment: Depends in your sql version, you can easily create a function in sql server to return greatest of two values. Or you can use ‘case’ in select, which I personally hates.

Comment: that's really close.  greatest doesn't exist in my version of sql-server.  but the code above gives me the following for Sue:

Name    contrib   trad_contrib     roth_contrib
Sue         500         60 (30+30)      150

trad_contrib should be 30+5